# Can we have different schemas in the Parquet and external tables of Hive?

Tags: hive, parquet, external-tables

In hive external tables and parquet files, can we have various data types but the same column names?
For example, can I have all fields in parquet files be text and define the data types in hive tables to be decimal, integer, or boolean?

For eg:
parquet schema:

```
root
 |-- empId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- refrenId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- position: string (nullable = true)
 |-- joiningdate: string (nullable = true)
```

hive :

```
|-- empId: integer (nullable = true)
|-- refrenId: integer (nullable = true)
|-- position: string (nullable = true)
|-- joiningdate: date(nullable = true)
```

If this is not feasible, how may this comparable capability with various data types be supported?